# Scikit-Learn manually specifying .max_features in RFECV()-how many features get ranked?

Tags: python, python-2.7, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have followed this [Scikit-Learn example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/ensemble/plot_forest_importances.html) in Python to obtain `.feature_importances_` from a forest estimator. In that example, `ExtraTreesClassifier()` was used with its default
hyperparameter settings - this would mean `max_features='auto'`. The output of this example is a plot of importances for 10 features.

**Question 1:**

When I re-run this example, with `max_features=2`, the plot is still showing feature importances for all 10 features. Should is only show the importances for 2 features?

**Question 2:**

Now, I would like to use `ExtraTreesClassifier(max_features=2)` with `RFECV()`. From the [RFECV() docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.RFECV.html), it indicates `RFECV()` assigns the best features a rank of 1 - we can see this in the `.ranking_` attribute of `RFECV()`. However, if I specify the estimator to be `ExtraTreesClassifier(max_features=2)`, then does `RFECV()` use 2 features in its estimator and only return ranks for 2 features? Or does it ignore `max_features` and return ranks for all the features?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`max_features` specifies how many features the learning algorithm looks at when deciding which feature provides the best split in a node of the tree. The features are randomly chosen for each node. So the decision tree still uses all features. It is just a way to speed up the learning.

Comment: So then are `max_features` not used in `RFECV()` at all?

Comment: What makes you think that?

Comment: When `RFECV()` selects features, it is looking at the ranking to select rank=1, but it doesn't seem to me that the estimator's `.feature_importances_` are being considered here. It is based on this that I would say that `RFECV()` is ignoring the `max_features` hyperparameter. Though I might be misunderstanding something....

Comment: ...and if the decision tree still uses all the features then that would explain why all the features are used to calculate the `.feature_importances_` attribute. Would this not suggest that the `max_features_` parameter is ignored by `RFECV()`?

Comment: `max_features_` does not limit number of features used for the whole tree but only for a single node. And each node can use a different subset of features to determine which to use to split the data. So the tree is always using all the features. Nothing gets ignored.

Comment: Thanks. That just cleared up the understanding for me.